# Python: How to assign column titles to each iteration of a for loop from an existing array

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I am a beginner. I have a static array from which I'd like to pull its variables successively and assign them as the column title to each iteration of a for loop. For example, after the first loop, assign the first variable in the col_titles as the column title. After the second loop, assign the second variable in the col_titles as the column title, and so on. Here's what I have going so far:

```
data = []

col_titles = ['30024`, '30033', '30038']

urls = [
'https://www.example.com/page1',
'https://www.example.com/page2',
'https://www.example.com/page3
]

counter = 1

for url in urls:
    driver.get(url)
    h2s = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'h2')
    try:
        for h2 in h2s:
            if counter <= 5:
                data.append(h2.get_attribute("innerText"))
                counter = counter + 1        
    except (ElementNotVisibleException, NoSuchElementException):
        data.append("None")
    driver.close()    

print(data)
```

Currently, the output is an array containing all the variables from each loop like so (with each h2 reflecting unique h2 titles from each url):

```
[h2, h2, h2, h2, h2, h2, h2, h2, None, None, h2, h2, h2, h2, None]
```

This is fine, as all I've done is append each iteration to the "data" array.

**This is where I get stuck.**

I think I should be creating a DataFrame within the for loop to grab a column title from the "col_titles" array, assigning it as a column title following (or preceding) each iteration of the for loop, but I don't know how to do this properly. What I'm hoping to achieve is an output like the following:

```
30024   30033   30038
h2      h2      h2
h2      h2      h2
h2      h2      h2
h2      None    h2
h2      None    None
```

Any insight is very appreciated!

Comment: When posting code here, please double-check that exactly what you post, copied and pasted, works—or at least, *doesn't* work in the way you describe. The code shown fails to compile, with a `SyntaxError`; the messed-up syntax highlighting here on StackOverflow is a hint.

Comment: @CrazyChucky Will do. I appreciate the guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) and `zip` function.
To get the result which is then passed to pandas DataFrame as columns/values it's more convenient in your case to use a dictionary-like data structure.

Instead of `data = []` initialize:

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = defaultdict(list)
```

Then you iterate over your `urls` and accumulate values for each *column* separately:

```
for col, url in zip(*[col_titles, urls]): 
    driver.get(url)
    h2s = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'h2')
    try:
        for h2 in h2s:
            if counter <= 5:
                data[col].append(h2.get_attribute("innerText"))
                counter = counter + 1        
    except (ElementNotVisibleException, NoSuchElementException):
        data[col].append("None")
    driver.close()
```

Eventually, when generating dataframe as `pd.DataFrame(data)` you'll get a structure like (similar) this:

```
  30024 30033 30038
0    h2    h2    h2
1    h2    h2    h2
2    h2    h2    h2
3    h2    h2    h2
4  None  None  None
```

Answer (score -1):

First you create dictionary, and add key from col_titles and assign value from each iteration which you get a list. And zip dictionary to dataframe-
Code will be something like -

```
col_titles = ['30024`, '30033', '30038']

urls = [
'https://www.example.com/page1',
'https://www.example.com/page2',
'https://www.example.com/page3
]

counter = 1
ctr = 0
my_dict={}

for url in urls:
    driver.get(url)
    h2s = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'h2')
    data = []
    try:
        for h2 in h2s:
            if counter <= 5:
                data.append(h2.get_attribute("innerText"))
                counter = counter + 1 
    except (ElementNotVisibleException, NoSuchElementException):
        data.append("None")
    driver.close()    
    ctr = ctr + 1 
    my_dict[col_titles[ctr]] = data
df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)
print(df)
```

Comment: Fails to compile with a `SyntaxError`